# Incompatible app on play store in Note 5

Tags: android

I have a note 5 and I cannot install the application but it works on other phones and tablet. I think it might have to do with the fact that phone has quad hd screen but other seems to be working fine. I don't know what else could be different. I went to google developer console and note 5 isn't even on the list of all devices.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="appnamemobile.company.com"
    android:versionCode="52"
    android:versionName="1.60">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"

        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        />

    <compatible-screens>
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>



        <!-- Special case for new phones with large screens 5"+ and Nexus 7 -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480"/>
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213"/>
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480"/>
    </compatible-screens>

    <!-- Features -->
    <!-- Required Features -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
              android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="false" />
    <!-- Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS">

    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.control_location_updates">

    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.install_location_provider">

    </uses-permission>
    <permission
        android:name="appnamemobile.company.com.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission  android:name="appnamemobile.company.com.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:name="appnamemobile.company.com.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="appnamemobile.company.com.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- Application as seen from the phone's menu -->
    <application
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/smalllogo"
        android:label=""
        android:name="application.GlobalApplication"
       android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        >
        <activity android:name="br.com.thinkti.android.filechooser.FileChooser"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            />
        <activity android:name="arcamera.ARCameraActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"

            android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
            />

        <receiver android:name="appnamemobile.company.com.LocationBaseFragment$MyBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="appnamemobile.company.com.RESPONSE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    <activity android:name="appnamemobile.company.com.LoginActivity" android:label="@string/geospotter"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden">

        >
        <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

         </intent-filter>   

    </activity>

    <activity android:name="appnamemobile.company.com.CameraActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" 
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:screenOrientation="landscape">



    </activity>
        <activity android:name="appnamemobile.company.com.MapViewActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
    <activity android:name="appnamemobile.company.com.CalendarActivity"
        >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="appnamemobile.company.com.CalendarActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="appnamemobile.company.com.FormObject"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" />

    <activity android:name="appnamemobile.company.com.ViewAssetActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        ></activity>
    <activity android:name="appnamemobile.company.com.SearchAssets"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"/>

        <activity android:name=".CalendarViewActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="appnamemobile.company.com.ActionBarActivity" />
        <activity android:name="appnamemobile.company.com.DummyInstructions"
            android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"/>
    <activity android:name=".SwipeActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="form.TaskModule"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" />
    <activity android:name="appnamemobile.company.com.SearchableActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
                <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                   android:resource="@xml/searchable"
                   android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="appnamemobile.company.com.TaskDetails" />
    <activity android:name="appnamemobile.company.com.FormIntro"
        android:configChanges="screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"/>
    <activity android:name="appnamemobile.company.com.CalendarSetup">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" android:resource="@xml/calendar_sync_adapter" />
    </activity>

         <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
   android:value="AIzaSyB95C5L_Jo2LvnZPAPZiOKspHjWGRPPeXQ" />
<meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
<service
            android:name="syncadapter.AuthenticatorService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data


      android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
        android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
    </service>

    <provider
        android:name="syncadapter.Provider"
        android:authorities="application.company.com.syncadapter.Provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:syncable="true"/>
    <service
                android:name="syncadapter.SyncService"
                android:exported="true"
                android:process=":sync"
                >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                    android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
        </service>
        <receiver
            android:name="syncadapter.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="appnamemobile.company.com" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="syncadapter.GcmIntentService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like if you must use the 'compatible-screen' tag you can do what you did for the 5+ and nexus 7 screens by allowing android:screenDensity="518" (the density for the [Note 5](http://www.phonearena.com/phones/Samsung-Galaxy-Note5_id9462)). I remember the Note 3 reported itself as a "normal" screen size though I'm not 100% sure what the Note 5 reports itself as.

Is there a reason you want to restrict certain screen types? It seems like Google may have stop supporting it if you cannot specify xxhdpi or xxxhdpi.

Comment: That seems to have been the issue, I took out all the code restricting screen size. Thanks